# How to make joins without explicit relation in Prisma?

Tags: prisma

I need to update a query in Prisma to make some future changes bearable. Which means the code is not currently optimal.

I do have three tables:

```
model Event {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  eventSettings     EventSettings[]
}

model EventSettings {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  orgId     Int
}

model Organization {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  publicId  String
}
```

The query I need to perfom is: return all events by organization, but I only can do this using the publicId. This is for an internal change in the code, and eventually everything will change to publicIds. But curerntly this is the way I need to do it.

I tried but I can't seem to make a code that Prisma will accept for the two joins. I need to search going through eventsettings > organization > events and return the list of events from X organization.

Doing include or where by organization seems to work only with the id, not publicId.